# How to configure Spring Gateway for correct routing

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-gateway

I created a Spring Eureka Registry, Spring Gateway and a Customer-Servvice.
On my local machine, everything works fine. I open my Registry and see there something like.

```
host.docker.internal:customer-management-ws:c390c86d4ab279fb780ad324347681b0
```

On click on it, I see a prepared info json with useful information of this service (acutator/info).

My Gateway runs on port 8011. If I call

```
localhost:8011/customer-management-ws/customer/all
```

I do a GET Request, that Gateway with integrated loadbalancer delegate my request to my runing customer ws...perfect.

=========

Today I deployed all three services to a external linux-server. Registry, Gateway and customer-ws running inside a docker container. So three docker container in total.

When I go to my new Eureka Registry URL I see something slightly different to my localhost.

```
 1ee684bc4d4e:customer-management-ws:8fef838e6471c0f72ce610d3c9b960a3
```

On click on it, nothing happens (page not found).

My docker Gateway runs on port 8011. If I call

```
myserver.org:8011/customer-management-ws/customer/all
```

That GET Request returns Error 500, docker logs of my gateway show me, this

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve '1ee684bc4d4e' after 2 queries
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1046) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar!/:4.1.67.Final]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
    Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/customer-management-ws/api/swagger-ui.html" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

Any Ideas how to fix that? What is 1ee684bc4d4e and why the loadbalancer cant resolve it to the docker customer-ws container behind it?

My docker customer-ws runs on port 8020. If do direct call

myserver.org:8020/customer/all

The get request is successfull.

Comment: the thing use see is the unique id. What does /eureka/apps say?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to run all three Docker Container inside same network.

1. Create bridge network
2. Run all container in this network.